# WP query is accessing posts from staging site, not main site

Tags: php, wordpress, staging

I used WP Staging Pro to create a staging site and then move it to my live site.  It looks ok but my queried posts are bringing up the posts in the staging directory.  So here's my code for the query.

```
$legal_array = query_posts(array(
    'cat' => 85,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'asc',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
));
```

The post generates with `https://mysite/staging/?p=3213` as the URL for the post instead of `https://mysite/?p=3213` for the post.  If I add a new post on the main site, it also shows up in the query and works fine.  All of the posts migrated and the permalinks for the migrated posts are correct.  I tried trashing all the staging posts, setting all the staging posts to Draft, using `wp_reset_query();`, `wp_reset_postdata();` and resetting the array with `$legal_array = [];`.  I also checked the wp_config.php file to see if anything was set to the staging URL and there was nothing.

Comment: Check-in your database, if any staging site URL missed updating with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure your website is connected to the right database i.e. LIVE database on the LIVE environment.
Check your wp-config.php file for this. I suggest you, set separate configurations for each environment (development, staging, production/live, etc) according to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I checked.  Everything in wp-config.php is correct.  Comparing it to the staging version, I can see where everything was reconfigured back to how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting support from WPStaging, where they spent a few days on their end fixing the problem